# OAuth2: Returning to App After Logging in

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I'm using a cocoapod named ([p2/OAuth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2)) in order to log in an account with **GitHub**.  I'm just playing because I want to know how OAuth2 works.

The following is what I have so far in my view controller (`UIViewController`).

```
import UIKit
import p2_OAuth2

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Variables
    let oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: [
        "client_id": "xxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxx",
        "authorize_uri": "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
        "token_uri": "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",   // code grant only
        "redirect_uris": ["myapp://oauth/callback"],   // register your own "myapp" scheme in Info.plist
        "scope": "user repo:status",
        "secret_in_body": true,    // Github needs this
        "keychain": false,         // if you DON'T want keychain integration
        ] as OAuth2JSON)

    // MARK: - IBOutlet

    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        oauth2.logger = OAuth2DebugLogger(.trace)
        oauth2.authorize() { authParameters, error in
            if let params = authParameters {
                print("Authorized! Access token is \(self.oauth2.accessToken ?? "")")
                print("Authorized! Additional parameters: \(params)")
            }
            else {
                print("Authorization was cancelled or went wrong: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is how to get back to the view controller after I successfully log in my account with GitHub.  So far, I will be redirected to the URL that I have registered at GitHub's developer website.  I suppose I need to register a callback URL scheme under `Info`.  This whole thing is totally new.  So I'm not sure how to do it.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have added a set of `URL types` through info.plist.  A URL scheme is set to myapp.  And the following is what I have in `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme == "myapp" && url.host == "oauth" {
        //oauth2.handleRedirectURL(url)
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView") as! UINavigationController
        let viewController = controller.topViewController as! ViewController
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

But the app never calls the above.

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt something new today.

1. At GitHub's developer website, I have set the call back URL as myapp://oauth/callback.  (See below.)

[image]

2. I have created a set of URL schemes through Info.plist.  An identifier is made with my reverse domain + a unique name.  A URL Schemes item is myapp.  (See below.)

[image]

3. Finally, I have added the following line of code to `AppDelegate`.

   ```
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
       if url.scheme == "myapp" && url.host == "oauth" {
           let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView") as! UINavigationController
           let viewController = controller.topViewController as! ViewController
           window?.rootViewController = viewController
       }
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
       return true
   }
   ```

If I log in, I get prompted as follows.

[image]

When I tap Open, I'm redirected to my view controller.